# A special case of the minimum number of multiplications used to compute a product of matrices

Tags: matrices, algorithms, computational-complexity

A fact about complexity of algorithms for computing the product of matrices was brought up to me that was very interesting I was not aware of.  I still am not sure what the optimal bound is on the minimum number of scalar multiplications to compute a product of $n \times n$ matrices (maybe it is a simple result in the $2 \times 2$ case?) but I was told there is at least a basic proof for the following case.  After playing around for a while I was not sure what the best route to take was so I thought I would just ask what is the easiest way to show the following result:

How do you prove that if $A,B$ are two $2 \times 2$ matrices then the product $AB$ can be computed using only 7 scalar multiplications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm).  You only use 7 scalar multiplications, and use 18 scalar additions (the standard method uses 8 scalar multiplications and 4 scalar additions).

Since addition is $O(n)$ (where $n$ is the number of bits of the two numbers) and multiplication is $O(n^2)$ (in the naive way; but there are better methods that are $O(n\log n 2^{\log_*n})$), for large enough numbers it is more efficient.

You can also iterate Strassen's algorithm to compue products of matrices by using the same formulas but with blocks instead of entries.